# multipart upload error in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload a file using AWS when i set the part size as 5MB the code works fine, but when i try to change the part size to 1MB it gives me an exception:
The code is

```
            string strusername = "user1";       
            strlocalpath = "C:\\file1.zip";    
            string BUCKET_NAME = "bucket1";
            string filename = "file1.zip"
            string keypath = strusername + "/" + filename;
            string keyName = "123";
            string filePath = strlocalpath;
            // List to store upload part responses.
            List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();

            // 1. Initialize.
            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest =
                new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME)
                .WithKey(keyName);

            InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
                s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

            // 2. Upload Parts.
            long contentLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
            //Set Part size 
            long partSize = 1*1024*1024; // 5 MB

            try
            {
                long filePosition = 0;
                for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
                {

                    if (filePosition + partSize > contentLength)
                    {
                        partSize = contentLength - filePosition;
                    }
                    // Create request to upload a part.
                    UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                        .WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME)
                        .WithKey(keyName)
                        .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
                        .WithPartNumber(i)
                        .WithPartSize(partSize)
                        .WithFilePosition(filePosition)
                        .WithFilePath(filePath)
                        .WithTimeout(60*60*60);

                    // Upload part and add response to our list.
                    uploadResponses.Add(s3Client.UploadPart(uploadRequest));

                    filePosition += partSize;



                    Console.WriteLine("\nTotal uploaded size = " + filePosition.ToString());
                }

                // Step 3: complete.
                CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest =
                    new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
                    .WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME)
                    .WithKey(keyName)
                    .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
                    .WithPartETags(uploadResponses);

                CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
                    s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(compRequest);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", exception.Message);
                s3Client.AbortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest()
                    .WithBucketName(BUCKET_NAME)
                    .WithKey(keyName)
                    .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId));
            }
```

The exception is:

```
<Error>
<Code>EntityTooSmall</Code>
<Message>Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size</Message>   
<ETag>d9c00192bcf6bf7412814a8fe0422b0c</ETag>
<MinSizeAllowed>5242880</MinSizeAllowed>
<ProposedSize>1048576</ProposedSize>
<RequestId>PBG04E031C012F34</RequestId>
<HostId>VEjvpkjuk89yS4xW6Bl/+NPpb3yxvbbe7ijjPmTrlXc7hnjj89kjkm</HostId> 
<PartNumber>1</PartNumber></Error>
```

I want to upload the file in chunks of 1 MB or 2MB is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: so basically it will not work for part size < 5MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum part size for S3 uploads is 5 MB.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html

Obviously, the last part will usually be smaller, which is fine.

A side effect of the fact that the "last part" can be smaller is that if you have, for example, a 500 KB file and you send it as a multipart upload, the "first part" is also the "last part" and this still works, because it satisfies the rule that the "last part" can be smaller than 5MB, but you still have to expressly use a part-size not smaller than 5 MB.

I discovered this while testing a multipart-uploaded that defaults to 64MB.  It still works fine on smaller files, which get multipart-uploaded as a single "part" which is less than 5MB.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got your sizing wrong.

S3 Documentation:
[Upload Part](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html)

> Each part must be at least 5 MB in size, except the last part. There
>   is no size limit on the last part of your multipart upload.

So no, you cannot specify to do parts less than 5MB.  When doing multipart, it will automatically allow the last part, assuming the last part is not the first/only part, to be less than 5MB.

---

Glacier Documentation:
[Amazon's Initiate MultiPart Upload documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-multipart-initiate-upload.html) states:

> When you initiate a multipart upload, you specify the part size in
>   number of bytes. The part size must be a megabyte (1024 KB) multiplied
>   by a power of 2—for example, 1048576 (1 MB), 2097152 (2 MB), 4194304
>   (4 MB), 8388608 (8 MB), and so on. The minimum allowable part size is
>   1 MB, and the maximum is 4 GB.

Your code has `long partSize = 1*1024*1024` which is `1048576` which is `1 MB` from the above, not 5MB as your comment states.

And ofnote for future reference or same issue, from the same link:

> Every part you upload using this upload ID, except the last one, must
>   have the same size. The last one can be the same size or smaller. For
>   example, suppose you want to upload a 16.2 MB file. If you initiate
>   the multipart upload with a part size of 4 MB, you will upload four
>   parts of 4 MB each and one part of 0.2 MB.

Comment: Actually, that's a reference to the Glacier documentation, not S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Upaded to include S3's answer with documentation.

Comment: yes it doesn't work for anything but for 5MB,i tried setting the size as 1MB and 2MB..but still no luck

Comment: @kunal Yes, documentation *clearly* states you cannot set the size below 5MB.

Comment: well said , kudos

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule:  If your file is less than 5Mb,  then upload it in one part.